# nginx & https redirection, webpage theme/images/formatting not working!! whats wrong?

Tags: http, redirect, nginx, https

May be some expert could revise my script please. I am noob and trying to setup nginx & drupal on my local pc.It was working fine except for HTTPS redirection and was getting the error message "port 80 443 HTTPS request blah blah".

I have found from this forum that adding the few lines of  "proxy_pass" coding (below) its possible to redirect, so I did. Thats working!! But the website theming and and formatting is removed now. All I can see is white page with links and texts. can anyone show me some light please?

```
  server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     localhost;
    return 301  https://$host$request_uri;
    #rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}
server {
    listen               443;
        server_name  localhost;
    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /srv/www/sslcerts/cdb.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /srv/www/sslcerts/cdb.key;
        error_page 497  https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;

    location / {
        root   /srv/www/cdb;
        index  index.php;
    #try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
##ADDED LATER & theme not working
            proxy_pass http://localhost:80;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto  https;
    }

location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
               try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
    root        /srv/www/cdb/;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #fastcgi_in;tercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /srv/www/cdb$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_buffer_size          128k;
        fastcgi_buffers            256 4k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size    256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ) {
         return 444;
    }

if ($http_user_agent ~* LWP::Simple|BBBike|wget|libwww-perl) {
            return 403;
    }

if ($http_user_agent ~* msnbot|scrapbot|Purebot|Baiduspider|Lipperhey|Mail.Ru) {
            return 403;
    }

if ( $http_referer ~* (babes|forsale|girl|jewelry|love|nudit|organic|poker|porn|sex|teen|viagra|nude|casino) )
     {
         return 403;
    }

location /images/ {
  valid_referers none blocked www.example.com example.com;
   if ($invalid_referer) {
     return   403;
    }
      }

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^ /index.php;
    }

#location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
 #               expires max;
  #              log_not_found off;
   #     }

location ~* /(images|cache|media|logs|tmp)/.*.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|sh|cgi)$ {
    return 403;
    error_page 403 /403_error.html;
    }

location ~ /\. {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the

```
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^ /index.php;
}
```

To

```
 location @rewrite {
     rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
 }
```

I think this configuration works if you are using clean urls.

Answer (score 0):

Got This working at last :)
this script worked with Clean URLs & http redirect to https port

```
  server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     localhost;
        return 301  https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    server {
        listen               443;
        server_name  localhost;
        ssl                  on;
        ssl_certificate      /srv/www/sslcerts/cdb.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /srv/www/sslcerts/cdb.key;
        error_page 497  https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;

    location / {
        root   /srv/www/cdb;
        index  index.php;
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
        }

    location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root        /srv/www/cdb/;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /srv/www/cdb$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_buffer_size          128k;
        fastcgi_buffers            256 4k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size    256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        }

    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ) {
        return 444;
        }

    if ($http_user_agent ~* LWP::Simple|BBBike|wget|libwww-perl) {
        return 403;
        }

    if ($http_user_agent ~* msnbot|scrapbot|Purebot|Baiduspider|Lipperhey|Mail.Ru) {
        return 403;
        }

    if ( $http_referer ~* (babes|forsale|girl|jewelry|love|nudit|organic|poker|porn|sex|teen|viagra|nude|casino) ) {
        return 403;
        }

    location /images/ {
      valid_referers none blocked www.example.com example.com;
    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return   403;
        }
          }

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
        }

    location ~* /(images|cache|media|logs|tmp)/.*.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|sh|cgi)$ {
        return 403;
        error_page 403 /403_error.html;
        }

    location ~ /\. {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        deny  all;
        }
    }
```